# RxJava observeOn() issue

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have two `PublishSubject`s and two `Observer`s subscribed respectively. Between `PubslishSubject` and `Subscriber` I switch from [main] thread to [RxSingleScheduler] thread using `observeOn(Schedulers.single())`. I start to publish (`PubslishSubject.onNext()`) on both `PublishSubject`s inside the loop.

```
publishSubject1.onNext("next");
publishSubject2.onNext("next");
```

What I expected was the both subscribers run in the same order as emissions were published but the results I get is completely different. Subsriber1 handles all it's emissions and then Subscriber2 handles all it's emissions.
I expected emission scheduled and run in publish order. Is there any way to achive this?

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class ObserveOnApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PublishSubject<String> publishSubject1 = PublishSubject.create();
        PublishSubject<String> publishSubject2 = PublishSubject.create();

        publishSubject1
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribe(next -> {
            System.out.println("Subscriber1");
        });

        publishSubject2
        .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
        .subscribe(next -> {
            System.out.println("Subscriber2");
        });

        for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
            publishSubject1.onNext("next");
            publishSubject2.onNext("next");
        }

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please in the future, do not [cross post](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6623) your issue on SO and the RxJava issue site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Schedulers Single is meant to execute work in sequence, check its [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#single--):

> Returns a default, shared, single-thread-backed Scheduler instance for work requiring strongly-sequential execution on the same background thread.

By the way, after running few times your code as it is, I was lucky enough to get the Subscribe1 to emit once, then Subscribe2 does its work and Subscribe1 finishes:

```
Subscriber1 // <- 1 started first!
Subscriber2 // <- then 2 started
Subscriber2
Subscriber2
...
Subscriber2
Subscriber2
Subscriber2 // <- 2 finished
Subscriber1 // <- 1 continued
Subscriber1
Subscriber1
...
```

If you don't have a specific requirement to use the `single` scheduler, try with [newThread](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#newThread--) or [io](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#io--), the result will be more like:

```
Subscriber1
Subscriber1
Subscriber2
Subscriber1
Subscriber2
Subscriber1
Subscriber2
Subscriber2
```

If you are always emitting the same items you don't need to create more than one PublishSubject, you can multicast it with the `publish` and call `connect` when you decide to start emitting items. You can also use `autoconnect` and pass the number of connections that will trigger the emission of items:

```
        PublishSubject<String> publishSubject1 = PublishSubject.create();

        Observable<String> stringObservable = publishSubject1.publish().autoConnect(2);

        stringObservable
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(next -> System.out.println("Subscriber1"));

        stringObservable
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(next -> System.out.println("Subscriber2"));

        for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
            publishSubject1.onNext("next");
        }

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you expect, you should use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())` instead of `observeOn`.

subscribeOn is a bit of tricky as it states on which thread the observable 'starts', while observeOn allows you to switch thread 'in the middle' of the operator sequence

check out the diffeirence between subscribeOn and observeOn here: 
https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a